# how to change dynamically column name in sql

Tags: sql

i have to change column name dynamically in loop in sql, using concat to add string and dynamic column name and getting error-'The definition for column 'CONCAT' must include a data type.'

this is my code-

```
SELECT @SOURCENAME='['+SOURCE_NAME+']' FROM #temptable2 WHERE  [id] = @StartRow;
                                                    SET @SQL='ALTER TABLE #TmpWcompData ADD '+@SOURCENAME+' float'
SET @SQL1='ALTER TABLE #TmpWcompData ADD concat(mae,'+@SOURCENAME+') float'
                                
                                
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL,@SQL1;
```

Comment: `concat` is inside the string, fix that.

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT` can’t be used in `ALTER TABLE`.
You can fix it as the following:

```
SET @SQL1 = 'UPDATE #TmpWcompData SET ' + @SOURCENAME + ' = CONCAT(mae, ' + @SOURCENAME + ')';
```